# ASP.NET Boilerplate misleading naming convention and files structure

Tags: naming-conventions, aspnetboilerplate

[ASP.NET Boilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/) creators claim their framework uses already familiar tools and implements **best practices** around them to provide you a SOLID development experience.

But I can't understand what the basis of some part of their naming convention and files structure.

For example, this is a part of their official [SimpleTaskApp](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Articles/Introduction-With-AspNet-Core-And-Entity-Framework-Core-Part-1/index.html) example:

```
[AutoMapFrom(typeof(Task))]
public class TaskListDto : EntityDto, IHasCreationTime
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

    public TaskState State { get; set; }
}
```

`TaskListDto` is very misleading! Isn't `TaskDto` more understandable?

Or why folders containing entities should be plural: ***Tasks**/Task.cs* or ***People**/Person.cs*.

Why are they kept apart at all? Is it not better to put all entities into one **Entites** folder in the Domain layer?

Answer (score 1):

I Do not have any experience with this framework but there is a concept in DDD called Domain Aggregates. It defines that entites with the same concept should be kept close together. For example we have a concept called people that some entities carry the same concept. We take Person as an aggregate root and all the other entities with the same concept are accessible via that aggregate root. So we keep the entites with the same concept under the same folder.
As of the TaskListDto I think the name should serve the purpose of the Class. And thus here we want to have a list of Tasks not a single task.

reading further about Domain Aggregates: https://www.jamesmichaelhickey.com/domain-driven-design-aggregates/